# New intent added in domain.yml does not show up in the UI and vice versa

Tags: rasa-nlu

I added a new intent `ques` to the started pack.

```
intents:
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - deny
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - ques
```

But i don't see it in the dropdown in Annotate new data tab in the UI.

Alternatively, adding new intent from the UI, does not update the domain.yml file.

How is this supposed to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rasa X are you running? The intents in the `annotate new data` view are fetched from the domain as of `0.19.2`. In any case, you can manually type in your intent, even if it doesn't appear in the dropdown